# good books to get deep into PHP

Tags: learning, php

I am a PHP developer with ~3 years experience.  I want to get deeper into PHP and really understand more low level constructs/functionality.  I have mainly done frontend web dev and a little php cron jobs.  I want to learn more about stream contexts, closures, process forking, etc.

The book I've found that seems closest to this is  [Expert PHP and MySQL (Wrox)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470563125).  I also found [Pro PHP](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1590598199).  I know there has to be more out there but I can't seem to find anything.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to suggest something else entirely: Become accustomed to learning from non-book resources. First of all, the three things you have mentioned in your question that you want to learn more about differ substantially. [Stream contexts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php) are part of the core php API, and can be thought of as a "framework feature". [Closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are a "language feature" (just another name for anonymous functions, really). Finally, [process forking](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/article/php/process-forking/) is more of an "OS feature", mostly available in *NIX flavor OS'es.

So what kind of book (with less than 1000s of pages) would include meaningful insights for these topics? I haven't read "Expert PHP and MySQL" but the name suggests that its focus is on something else.

So I want to suggest that you start reading the [PHP language reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php). It has all the details about all the topics there are. If some general computer science terms are unknown to you, you ask a question on SO or read up on it on wikipedia. If you find a topic in the reference that you don't understand or don't see the point of, you skip it, but make a mental note of the topic's existence so that you can return to it at a later time. The pro's of this approach are that you yourself can choose the focus of your study and do not have to rely on finding a book that covers your immediate interests. Furthermore, online documentation is usually more up-to-date than books, and online docs are also free. Granted, this approach takes a little getting used to and maybe also requires better analytical skills, but in the long run it is a much faster way to learn.

Afterall, in todays market, who has the time to wait for a book to arrive?

Answer (score 0):

I kind of agree that learning php is usually not learned by books. But, there are many people who learn better by reading a book for some reasons (me included). I believe that the market is not mature enough. I would suggest something like this:

[Head first labs, php book](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/) (I have not read it but everything from the head first series is great)

and honestly difficult on thinking something else...